# Same exact query produce 2 different results MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, database-administration

I have a query. In the local database, it returns the static prices - preco, preco_boleto (always the same); already but in production (remote) these prices are changing almost at each execution. 
It is the same code, query and database.

Local database version: 5.6.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
Production database version: 5.6.30-76.3-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 76.3, Revision 3850db5

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
concat_ws(' ',
        `f`.`descricao`,
        concat_ws(' ', ccc.descricao)) as descricao,
concat(concat(ccc.fan_rpm_minimo,
                ' - ',
                ccc.fan_rpm_maximo),
        ' RPM') as rpm,
concat(concat(round(ccc.nivel_ruido_minimo, 1),
                ' - ',
                round(ccc.nivel_ruido_maximo, 1),
                ' dbA')) as ruido,
`ccc`.`nivel_ruido_maximo` as `ruido_padrao`,
`ccc`.`slug`,
`cor`.`descricao` as `cor`,
`h`.`hash`,
`hp`.`preco`,
`hp`.`preco_boleto`
FROM
`cooler_cpu` `ccc`
    INNER JOIN
`fabricante` `f` ON `f`.`fabricante_id` = `ccc`.`fabricante_id`
    LEFT JOIN
`cor` ON `cor`.`cor_id` = `ccc`.`cor_id`
    LEFT JOIN
`hash` `h` ON `ccc`.`hash_id` = `h`.`hash_id`
    LEFT JOIN
(select 
    hp.peca_id, hp.preco, hp.preco_boleto, hp.link
from
    historico_preco hp
where
    peca_tipo_id = 2
        and execucao_id = (select 
            max(execucao_id)
        from
            historico_preco)
        and preco is not null
order by hp.preco asc) hp ON `hp`.`peca_id` = `ccc`.`cooler_cpu_id`
WHERE
(`checado_basico` = 1
    or `checado_completo` = 1)
GROUP BY `ccc`.`cooler_cpu_id`
ORDER BY ISNULL(1) , 1 ASC
LIMIT 50
```

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE `historico_preco` (
`historico_preco_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`peca_tipo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`loja_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`peca_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`execucao_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`parcela` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`preco` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`preco_boleto` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`link` varchar(2100) DEFAULT NULL,
`data` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`historico_preco_id`),
KEY `fk_preco_loja1_idx` (`loja_id`),
KEY `fk_historico_preco_peca_tipo1_idx` (`peca_tipo_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_historico_preco_peca_tipo1` FOREIGN KEY (`peca_tipo_id`)       REFERENCES `peca_tipo` (`peca_tipo_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_preco_loja1` FOREIGN KEY (`loja_id`) REFERENCES     `loja`         (`loja_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34611 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```